# github api v3 repository create

Tags: social-media

I'm trying to create a github repository form a notebook, using this simple code

```
token = "bftoken";
url = "https://api.github.com/user/repos";

data = URLFetch[url, 
 "Parameters" -> {"access_token" -> token, "name" -> "test"}, 
 "Method" -> "POST"]
```

but I get this result

```
{"message":"Requires \
  authentication","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3"}
```

My token has "full access", so I guess that's not the  problem.
Could you give me some pointers on how to login(and create this repo)

Comment: That is not what I get. I get a prompt asking me to login. ![Mathematica graphics](http://i.stack.imgur.com/QAy7C.png)  only when you hit the CANCEL button, do I get the message you show. So, you need to actually sign in.

Comment: So "access_token" and "name" are your login and password parameters?

Comment: @Nasser, yes, I get the prompt too, and then I enter my credentials, but still can't create a repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This did the trick

```
URLFetch["https://api.github.com/user/repos", 
 "Headers" -> {"Authorization" -> "token " <> token}, 
  "BodyData" -> "{\"name\":\"test012\"}", "Method" -> "POST"]
```